# Linear functions of $X$

Tags: statistics

> From my stats textbook, If $X$ has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, the standardised version of $X$, has mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

Then it states this,

> $$E\left [ \sum_{i}^{}  c_ig_i(x)) \right ]=\sum_{i}^{} c_i E\left [ g_i(x) \right ]$$

What actually it means? I've no idea at all.

Comment: There is no connection between these two statements, and no doubt there is some explanatory text in between, which you don't show us. The second identity exresses the linearity of the expectation operator.

Comment: What is unclear to you?

Comment: Depends what the $g_i$ are, essentially it is saying that the expectation of a linear combination of (standardized) random variables is a linear combination of the expectation of (standardized) random variables.

Comment: @Eldioo The first statement seems no connection with the second.

Comment: @Bacon: no, that doesn't depend on the particular $g_i$s.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Fair enough, I was hedging my bets in case there are some underlying infromation on the $g_i$ the OP has not told us.

Comment: @Mathxx You are correct in stating that a connection lacks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Expectation is a linear operator (on the space of integrable functions). $\sum_i c_ig_i(x)$ is a linear combination of functions $g_i(\cdot)$ and $\sum_ic_iE[g_i(x)]$ is a linear combination of the expectation of those functions.